# Angular and .net Core API Toasty Notification recognize Error but it's not

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core-2.0

[image][image]Inside of project I had include global error handling.

```
import { ErrorHandler,Inject, NgZone } from "@angular/core";
import { ToastyService } from "ng2-toasty";

export class AppErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    constructor(
        @Inject(ToastyService) private toastyService: ToastyService,
        @Inject(NgZone)private ngZone: NgZone
    ) { }
    handleError(error: any): void {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
            this.toastyService.error({
                title: 'Error',
                msg: error.text(),
                theme: 'bootstrap',
                showClose: true,
                timeout: 5000
            });
        });


    }

}
```

For one controller,when I call Get, controller is returning data, which should be display on web page. But for some reason I'm not getting displayed data, instead if I check console of web page I find an error: **TypeError: error.text is not a function.**
Here is print screen where can see response and this error.
[image]
Why I'm getting this error only for this controller, not for other controllers ?

**Here is my target controller.cs**

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<object> Get()
        {
            var subCodes = await _repository.GetSubCodesAsync();

            if (subCodes == null)
                return NotFound();

            var response = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<SubCodes>, IEnumerable<SubCodeResponse>>(subCodes);

            return Ok(response);
        }
```

Update:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";
import { SubCode } from "../models/index";

@Injectable()
export class SubCodeService {

    private readonly API_URL = 'http://localhost:52840/api/subcode/';

    constructor(private http: Http,
        private authService: AuthService) { }

    getSubCodes() {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Authorization', "Bearer " + this.authService.token);

        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this.http.get(this.API_URL, options).map(res => res.json());
    }

    getSubCodeById(id) {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Authorization', "Bearer " + this.authService.token);

        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this.http.get(this.API_URL + id, options).map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

Compare two controllers and show data from different controller:
[image][image]

Comment: paste you'r service.ts code also .

Comment: I have added subcode.service.ts

Comment: The problem is from **msg: error.text(),** part in **AppErrorHandler** . try to debug it with putting breakpoint or add Debugger; for more information i need to have you'r whole code.

Comment: Okay, can you explain me why? that error.text() is displaying error when error really happen. Why should now that is a problem only for this controller ?

Comment: When you call this controller , will **msg: error.text(),** fire ? put a debugger at it's top and see what **error** contain . I'm sure **error** doesn't have any function called **text()** .

Comment: that is fire only when Controller return BadRequest. Other controllers has same code only different data, and when I call other API Controllers don't have problem. Will update you question in order to show you.

Comment: Please put 2 more photos . 1. Headers tab of you'r inspect , 2. Preview tab of you'r inspect

Comment: Please check photos

Comment: You should find the problem with debugging step by step . try re-run npm again , restart IIS , and review you'r error handler library ...